# Find largest (or smallest) element in unordered array in one statement while preserving order

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I know how to find the largest and smallest elements of a Java:

1. sort the array
2. use a for loop to iterate over the array and check for the smallest.

But is there a way to check for the largest or smallest in one statement? Also, order needs to be preserved.

Conditions:

1. No method calls in the same class
2. Sequence is unsorted, and remains unsorted
3. No access to external libraries (i.e. `ArrayUtils` is not allowed).

Assume that this is a plain Java array, i.e. `int[]`, not `ArrayList<T>` or `LinkedList<T>`.

Comment: If it's naturally sorted, largest and smallest are first/last or last/first elements (depending on the sort order), why the loop!?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is unsorted (I put unordered in the title, but meant unsorted).

Comment: @user473973 what RC meant: If you sort the array in step 1, you don't have to loop because the smallest element is then the first element of the array - that's what sorting usually does!

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer arr[] = new Integer[50];
// fill the array with integers
Collections.min(Arrays.asList(arr));
Collections.max(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

**Example:**

```
Integer arr[] = {7, 8, 1, 2, 6};
System.out.println(Collections.min(Arrays.asList(arr)));
System.out.println(Collections.max(Arrays.asList(arr)));
```

**Output:**

```
1
8
```

If you must use `int[]` instead of `Integer[]` with the one statement constraint as proposed, you can make use of [`ArrayUtils.toObject`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28int%5B%5D%29) function which will convert the `int[]` to it's corresponding wrapper class `Integer[]`. But i don't think you are after using external library though.

Comment: Slightly cheating, but as `asList()` wrapps the array it is probably allowed. For performance direct array access will be faster, so be aware of huge arrays.

Comment: this won't work with `int[]` however

Comment: yup, but OP requires the operation in one statement. Here it is, in one statement ;) :P